# What does "pcntl_fork(): Error 12" mean?

Tags: php, linux, multiprocessing

I've searched until I was blue in the face and cannot find the answer to this question.

Where I can find a table listing the meanings of all the error codes for pcntl_fork()? Or even the C fork() function, for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page for the function describes the possible errors in the **ERRORS** section. The mapping between error name and number can be found in /usr/include/asm-generic/errno*.h, or via `perror` if you have MySQL installed.

Answer (score 9):

It seems the `12` error code indicates there was not enough memory to fork.

See [this post](http://www.techlists.org/archives/web/apache-users/2002-03/msg00301.shtml), for instance *(quoting)* :

> I've had this when 
> (1) I've run out of
>   memory, and 
> (2) when the pid table is
>   full.  In the latter case a rogue
>   program was constantly forked child
>   processes & not picking-up the message
>   when they die.  The result was >200
>   zombies.

Answer (score 0):

console command

> perror 12

"OS error code  12:  Cannot allocate memory"